# Cannot find symbol error while converting Celsius to Fahrenheit Java

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am really new to all of this stuff and I am trying to convert `Celsius` to `Fahrenheit` in `jGRASP Java`. The code i am using is attached in the picture, also the error can be seen in the other picture.

[image: thats the code i am using]

<kbd>Error message</kbd>

[image: the following is the error]

Comment: [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and reform your question according to it.

Comment: Please post the relevant code, don't attach it as picture

Answer (score 0):

The message says everything. You didn't declare `F` yet, thus the compiler cannot find the symbol. Declare it before using it like

```
int F = 0;
```

EDIT: You probably meant to compare `input` with the string literal `"F"`. You have to declare `input` as a `string`, read a `string` variable into it and then use the `if` clause like

```
if (input == "F") {//...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (input == F)
```

In the code which you provided, you never declare F.

Judging by the code you want to see if the users entered an "F", however you assign the input variable as such:

```
int input = scan.nextInt();
```

It would be better to do something like this:

```
String input = scan.nextLine();

if(input.equals("F")){
// rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are telling the scanner to read an int data and you are expecting a text or a character. Using scanner.next() will return what comes before a space as a string . Then you can check it's value. Here is an example that does it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String tempScale = "";
        System.out.print("Enter the current outside temperature: ");
        double temps = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Celsius or Farenheit (C or F): ");
        String input = scanner.next();
        if ("F".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
            temps = (temps-32) * 5/9.0;
            tempScale = "Celsius.";
        } else if ("C".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
            temps = (temps * 9/5.0) + 32;
            tempScale = "Farenheit.";
        }
        System.out.println("The answer = " + temps + " degrees " + tempScale);
        scanner.close();
  }
```

And an illustration:

[image]